# how to create a web page with web service in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am new in ASP.NET and C# and I want to do a web page with web service in visual studio.

I did this: http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-web-service-in-cnet.html#.UMnF3uQzyTw

But, how can I implement a web page in the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new web project and consume the web service in side that.

This link may help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the web page to run in a separate ASP.Net web project which then references the web service you've written, they don't sit in the same project.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134052/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100803-1.aspx) might help.